# Missing required parameters for [Route: empresas.update] [URI: empresas/{empresa}]

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, crud, laravel-8

He visitado otras preguntas del foro pero no logro aclararme ya que soy nueva en esto de usar laravel, apenas hace una semana que me han explicado y es mi primer proyecto que hago sola.

Me sale el siguiente problema:

> Missing required parameters for [Route: empresas.update] [URI:
> empresas/{empresa}]. (View:
> C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\laravel8_borsa\resources\views\Empresas\edit.blade.php)

He estado revisando el codigo pero no entiendo que puede estar mal, he seguido este [tutorial](https://xpertphp.com/laravel-8-crud-create-read-update-delete-tutorial-for-beginners/) En el que explica los pasos a seguir pero yo he modificado estudiante por empresa.

He visto en otra pregunta que el usuario que tenía el problema usara php artisan route:list asi que he realizado esto hasta la aliminación

```
\EmpresasController@update  | web        |
|        | DELETE    | empresas/{empresa}      | empresas.destroy | App\Http\Controllers
```

Esto es lo que aparece en mi consola, adjunto el edit.blade.php ya que nose si estoy haciendo alguna cosa erroneamente.

```
@extends('Empresas.layout')

@section('content')
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-11">
            <h2>Update Empresa</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-1">
            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ url('empresas') }}"> Back</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    @if ($errors->any())
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <strong>Whoops!</strong> Hay algun problema con os datos introducidos.<br><br>
            <ul>
                @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                    <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        </div>
    @endif
    <form method="post" action="{{ route('empresas.update',$empresas->id) }}" >
        @method('PATCH')
        @csrf
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="txtCompanyName">Nombre de la empresa:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtCompanyName" placeholder="Nombre de la empresa" name="txtCompanyName" value="{{ $empresas->company_name }}">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="txtAddress">Direccion:</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="txtAddress" name="txtAddress" rows="10" placeholder="Direccion">{{ $empresas->address }}</textarea>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </form>
@endsection
```

También he revisado mi controlador, de Empresas donde tengo la sección de update, ya que realmente no se en que archivo estaría el error:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'txtCompanyName'=>'required',
            'txtAddress' => 'required'
        ]);
 
 
        $empresas = Empresas::find($id);
        $empresas->company_name = $request->get('txtCompanyName');
        $empresas->address = $request->get('txtAddress');
 
        $empresas->update();
        
        return redirect('/empresas')->with('success', 'La empresa ha sido editada correctamente'); 
    }
```

Adjunto la migración a la base de datos por si puede servir de ayuda para saber que problema podrodría estar ocurriendo:

```
class CreateEmpresasTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('empresas', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('company_name');
            $table->text('address');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('empresas');
    }
}
```

Adjunto el archivo de rutas:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\OfertasController;
use App\Http\Controllers\EmpresasController;
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

  
Route::resource('ofertas', OfertasController::class);
Route::resource('empresas', EmpresasController::class);
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

Muchas gracias!! y disculpar las molestias.

Comment: Prueba generar la url así `route('empresas.update', ['empresa' => $empresas->id])`

Comment: Lo que no me devuelve a la pagina donde deberia devolver me sale not found error 404

Comment: Como es eso de que sacaste los corchetes? Los corchetes deben quedar, a lo que me refería es al action del form `action="{{ route('empresas.update', ['empresa' => $empresas->id]) }}"`

Comment: sin los corchetes sale la página, con los corchetes seguía dando el mismo error que me salía de un principio, el unico fallo es que no devuelve correctamente a la página de regreso

Comment: Estás segura de que `$empresas->id` tiene un valor, y no está devolviendo `null`? Es un modelo eloquent? Sería útil si publicas el método del controlador que devuelve esa vista

Comment: como coloco lo que devuelve? a que te refieres

Comment: public function edit(Empresas $empresas)
    {
        return view('empresas.edit',compact('empresas'));
    }

Comment: Prueba pasarle directamente el modelo `action="{{ route('empresas.update', ['empresa' => $empresas]) }}"`

Comment: Nada sale el error Missing required parameters for [Route: empresas.update] [URI: empresas/{empresa}]. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\laravel8_borsa\resources\views\Empresas\edit.blade.php)

Answer (score 2):

Aparentemente, tienes un problema de binding. Tu ruta está construida con un parámetro llamado `{empresa}`:

```
empresas/{empresa}
```

Pero en tu controlador no recibes dicha variable, si no que usas `$id`:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
```

Lo que debes hacer es simplemente cambiar `$id` por `$empresa` en tu controlador. Algo aún mejor, es hacer uso de la inyección de dependencias y dejar tu método de esta manera:

```
use App\Model\Empresa;
...
public function update(Request $request, Empresa $empresa)
```

Comment: He probado a cambiar lo que me has dicho ya aparece Missing required parameters for [Route: empresas.update] [URI: empresas/{empresa}]. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\laravel8_borsa\resources\views\Empresas\edit.blade.php) diria que es el mismo error

Comment: `public function update(Request $request, $empresa = 0)` solo dejalo como el parámetro, y ponle un valor por defecto, el problemas es que no lo estas pasando, y ya estas generando el modelo,

Comment: Siempre cometo el mismo error... pongo un nombre en la ruta y otro en el controlador! gracias por recordarmelo

Answer (score 0):

Comprueba que la variable empresa realmente te esté pasando el valor de dicha empresa.

Seguramente en el edit tienes que hacer un find del id que recibes.

```
public function edit($id)
{
        
        $empresa = Empresas::find($id);
        
        
        return view('empresa.edit',compact('empresa')); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes escrito:
route('empresas.update',$empresas->id)

Debes modificar con los corchetes:
route('empresas.update',['id' => $empresas->id])

Ya que estas pasando un parametro que se llama ID.

Comment: Cuando tengas suficiente reputación podrás hacer comentarios a las respuestas, por mientras revisa [Como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)